# Como chamar class por class, pegando apenas a que o mouse estiver sobre a mesma, sem pegar as outras simultaneamente?

Tags: php, css3

Eu quero ao passar o mouse sobre cada class e chamar o seu **form** sem chamar o **form** de todas as outras. Alguém pode me ajudar? No meu caso eu vou ter varias class de nome **lis-fil** e toda vez que passo o mouse sobre a class é chamado o formulário das mesmas. porém eu quero chama apenas da class que eu estiver com o mouse.

```
     <div class="lis-fil">
         <a href="jumanji-bem-vindo-a-selva.php"><img src="_img/capas/jumanji.jpg" class="fil-lis"></a>
         <form action=""><?php  ?></form>
      </div>

      <div class="lis-fil">
        <a href="no-olho-do-furacao.php"><img src="_img/capas/no-olho-do-furacao.jpg" class="fil-lis"></a>
        <form action=""><?php  ?></form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Você usao javascript puro ou alguma biblioteca para auxiliar a interação da DOM da sua página ? Como por exemplo o Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara não sei se eu entendi direito o que vc queria, mas como vc colocou a tag CSS, Vou te dar uma solução com `nth-child(n)` *(**n** é o número da ordem em que a `div` aparece, como vc tem duas `div` usei 1 e 2 no exemplo)* vc consegue fazer um estilo a parte para cada `div` com a classe `lis-fil`

Os dois `Form` começam ocultos com `display:none`, porém ao passar o mouse sobre a respectiva `div` o Form aparece.

Repare que nas classes `div.lis-fil form` e `div.lis-fil:hover form` eu faço os estilos que são comuns a todas as `div.lis-fil`. Depois usando `div.lis-fil:nth-child(1):hover form` eu coloco o estilo particular de cada uma das `div`, no caso só troco a cor de texto para cada div nesse exemplo.

```css
div.lis-fil form{
    display: none;
}
div.lis-fil:hover form{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
div.lis-fil:nth-child(1):hover form{
    color:red;
}
div.lis-fil:nth-child(2):hover form{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="lis-fil">
    <a href="jumanji-bem-vindo-a-selva.php"><img src="http://placecage.com/50/50" class="fil-lis"></a>
    <form action="">form1 lis-fil </form>
</div>

<div class="lis-fil">
    <a href="no-olho-do-furacao.php"><img src="http://placecage.com/51/50" class="fil-lis"></a>
    <form action="">form2 lis-fil </form>
</div>

<div class="lis-fil">
    <a href="no-olho-do-furacao.php"><img src="http://placecage.com/52/50" class="fil-lis"></a>
    <form action="">form3 sem classe nth-child(n) </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Se os dados forem dinâmicos, sua solução fica engessada, a menos que o usuário faça também laços para o CSS.

Comment: Na verdade não necessariamente, pois mostrar o form é algo comum a todas as divs, etão ele não precisa do nth-child para fazer aparecer o form, ele só precisa do nth-child caso queira customizar cada um dos forms de cada div.Se for esse o caso dele ai sim seria interessante fazer essa dinâmica

Comment: @EliseuB. inclusive até editei e coloquei o form3 que não tem formatação nth-child(n), porem só aparece no :hover da div pai dele.

Comment: A sem child atende, simplifica para o dono da pergunta então, removendo a condição com uso de childs =)

Comment: Seu complemento sem child levou meu voto, valeu companheiro.

Comment: @EliseuB. valeu meu caro, a opção do nth-child é apenas se ele quiser um CSS para cada form, mas não para mostrar e esconder cada forme, pois essa é uma condição comum a todos. []´s

Comment: Cara você é demais, e agora pareceu tão simples vendo da forma que você falou, no meu caso acho que já vou deixar o chamado feito do formulario em php, com isso vai ficar apenas oculto, e então eu chamo usando o :hover chamando a class filha da div.lis-fil, e ficou muito mais simples ainda, obrigado @hugocsl por me ajudar, agora é certeza que vou conseguir fazer o que eu tanto bati cabeça aqui

Comment: @FabrícioPatrocinio que bom que ajudou, o simples as vezes é o mais difícil de se pensar. O problema deixa a gente cego, mas um olhar de fora as vezes ajuda. Boa sorte com o projeto.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, conhecimento assim obtido com a ajuda de alguém que se preocupa em ajudar o próximo e algo vindo de Deus. Graças a pessoas como você que eu vou conseguir construir meu site de filmes de uma forma bem dinamica e diferencial de todos esses sites que eu mesmo acesso

Comment: Fabrício, vota e avalia a resposta como a correta pra você, assim ajuda o próximo que também pode vir a ter a mesma dificuldade e contribui com todos também, abraços.

Comment: @FabrícioPatrocinio ensinar é um prazer que só se aprende fazendo, isso enriquece o ser humano. Vc está no caminho certo. Foque nos fundamentos, evite soluções prontas e vc vai crescer muito mais! Sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará usar jquery ou javascript puro aqui segue um exemplo

```
<script>
    $(".lis-fil").mouseover(function(){
       var divAutal = $(this);
       var formAtual = divAtual.find("form");
       formAtual.submit();
    });
</scrit>
```

pronto agora você pode fazer  o que quiser com a div ou form
você pode baixar o  [jquery aqui](https://code.jquery.com)

Comment: Antes legal saber se o usuário faz uso de Jquery, não impor a ele o uso, caso responda, dê a solução em javascript puro também, ou questione primeiramente.

Comment: Estou tentando chamar usando AJAX porém não esta dando certo, oq eu devo fazer para que esse codigo aconteça, eu tenho um formulario em php e estou tentando chamar ele ousando o mouseover e esse codigo que você me passou,porém não esta dando certo
$(".lis-fil").mouseover(function () {
   var divAutal = $(this);
       var formAtual = divAtual.find("form");
        formAtual.submit();
   var regiao = $(this).attr("class");
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "inf-float.php", 
    data: "regiao", 
    success: function(dados){
     $(".inf-float").html(dados);
    }
   });
  });

Comment: Ne desculpe por não ter feito a pergunta direito, mas o formulario não vai existi ali dentro da div, eu vou add ele usando ajax

Comment: Tem a resposta do @hugocsl que é bacana, ajuda até na performance do site, e faça uso do recurso "editar" pergunta, para incrementar a explicação do seu problema, e estas questões de quais recursos você irá dispor no seu código, assim facilita pra todos, abraço.

Comment: Obrigado @Eliseu B. você me ajudou a compreender mais um pouco o que o colega encima disse, agora vou conseguir fazer o que tanto esperava.